# run a nodejs web server, and display its main page

Tags: node.js, browser

I would like to write a node.js script that runs a web server, and when the server has
started, opens a page in the default browser.
To do the latter, I have tried the npm package "open", which works perfectly, except for
pages delivered by the local server just started.
The script is something like:

```
http.createServer(function(request,response){
   ... usual stuff
}).listen(8001);
open('http://www.localhost:8001/index.html');
```

I suspect that the reason is that the server is not actually started when the open is
executed, but I have tried to put it in a timer, firing it after few seconds, and the
result is the same.

Comment: Solved. I have removed "www." from the url. The last statement now is:open('http://localhost:8001/index.html');

Answer (score 4):

Call open in the callback.

For example

```
http.createServer(function(request,response){
   ... usual stuff
}).listen(8001,function(){
   open('http://localhost:8001/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because NODE is asynchronous !
the open function is getting called before its gets a call back from the listen function ! 
so always do stuff after u get callback ! this is not like the procedural programming ! 
so Use : `http.createServer(function(request,response){
   ... usual stuff
}).listen(8001,function(){
   open('http://www.localhost:8001/index.html');
});`